# How to create one dynamic List<List<string>>?

Tags: c#, list

I want to read some text in a file. The text is like:

A

////

B

C

///

D

E

F

////

I want to create one `List<List<string>>` for store up the data. So I program like this:

```
 List<string> event = new List<string>();
 List<List<string>> eventList = new List<List<string>>();

 System.IO.StreamReader f = new System.IO.StreamReader("list.txt");
 string line = f.ReadLine();
 while (line != null && (! line.Equals("")))
 {
     if (line[0].Equals('/'))
     {
         eventList.Add(event);
         event.Clear();
     }
     else
     {

          event.Add(line);       
     }
     line = f.ReadLine();

 }
```

**What I want to get** is one list of lists, where the first list is A, second list is B, C and the third list is D,E,F

**But what I got** is also one list of lists, where the first list is D,E,F, the second list and the third list are both D,E,F

Could somebody know how to debug it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
 eventList.Add(event);
```

You are not **copying** the `event` list - you are adding a **reference** to it to the `eventList`. So when you do this:

```
event.Clear();
```

It affects the list you just added (because it's the same object). So you are only working with a single list. And therefore when you've finished, your eventList ends up having three references to the **same** list, which contains the things you added after you last cleared it.

Instead of `event.Clear()`, you should make a new list: `event = new List<string>();`